# IE8 shadow with css

Tags: css

I was wondering how I can get shadow on all sides of a div in IE8. In addition to this I want another div that got shadow on all sides but the top.

I have managed to get the shadow on the right and bottom, but not around all 4 sides.. What does the direction property tell me? I have tried with different directions but with no success..

`filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength = 4, Direction = 135, Color = '#cccccc');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible to use css shadows with ie (only ie9). 
But you can use [shadowOn](http://shadowon.codeplex.com/). It's a great Image based jquery plugin and very easy in use to add shadows to html elements.

Comment: But what about -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')"; ?

Answer (score 0):

you can emulate what you want with http://css3pie.com/

that, or just add a partially transparent div behind your object that's slightly larger to act as a fake shadow

Comment: sharma's answer below also looks helpful-- and shadowOn claims to be compatible with ie8 as he said, so give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

You may work around CSS Borders having glow effect ***[here](http://tumblr.gesteves.com/post/475773360/css-glow-effects-with-box-shadow)***. You may change the colors and some others parameters.

Hope this helps.